# Python script can retrieve value from memcache, but PHP script gets empty result

Tags: php, python, memcached

i run a python script whitch cache some data

```
self.cache.set('test', 'my sample data', 300)
data = self.cache.get('test')
self.p(data)
```

this program will result in print of 'my sample data' ... everything its good, but when i try to access this key from php

```
$data = $this->cache->get('test');
print_r($test);
```

i only get empty result
so i check the server stats

```
$list = array();
$allSlabs = $this->cache->getExtendedStats('slabs');
$items = $this->cache->getExtendedStats('items');
foreach($allSlabs as $server => $slabs) {
    foreach($slabs AS $slabId => $slabMeta) {
        $cdump = $this->cache->getExtendedStats('cachedump',(int)$slabId);
            foreach($cdump AS $server => $entries) {
                if($entries) {
                foreach($entries AS $eName => $eData) {
                    $list[$eName] = array(
                        'key' => $eName,
                        'server' => $server,
                        'slabId' => $slabId,
                        'detail' => $eData,
                        'age' => $items[$server]['items'][$slabId]['age'],
                    );
                }
                }
            }
        }
    }
ksort($list);
print_r($list);
```

and this key 'test' is there ... but i cannot access it

if i cache something in php i get the result everytime, but somehow this python + php cache wont work

if someone has an idea where could be a problem plese advice ... i try everything

Comment: Could you include a relevant excerpt from the output of the 'check server stats' code snippet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be that the hashes don't match between PHP and Python? A solution is here: http://www.ruturaj.net/python-php-memcache-hash

Add the following to your Python script to change how hashes are calculated...

```
import memcache
import binascii
m = memcache.Client(['192.168.28.7:11211', '192.168.28.8:11211
', '192.168.28.9:11211'])

def php_hash(key):
    return (binascii.crc32(key) >> 16) & 0x7fff

for i in range(30):
       key = 'key' + str(i)
       a = m.get((php_hash(key), key))
       print i, a
```